# throw er; error in jQuery code - WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have written the following jQuery code to show a popup when user reaches the end of page. For some reason its giving me error:

```
throw er;
```

Code:

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#popup-container a.close').click(function(){
          jQuery('#popup-container').fadeOut();
          jQuery('#active-popup').fadeOut();
        });

        var visits = jQuery.cookie('visits') || 0;
        visits++;

        jQuery.cookie('visits', visits, { expires: 1, path: '/' });

        console.debug(jQuery.cookie('visits'));
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
          if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() === jQuery(document).height()) {
            if (jQuery.cookie('visits') > 1) {
              jQuery('#active-popup').hide();
              jQuery('#popup-container').hide();
            } else {
              var pageHeight = jQuery(document).height();
              jQuery('<div id="active-popup"></div>').insertBefore('body');
              jQuery('#active-popup').css("height", pageHeight);
              jQuery('#popup-container').show();
            }
          }
        }
        if (jQuery.cookie('noShowWelcome')) { jQuery('#popup-container').hide(); jQuery('#active-popup').hide(); }
      });
```

Code for cookie:

```
  var pluses = /\+/g;

  function encode(s) {
    return config.raw ? s : encodeURIComponent(s);
  }

  function decode(s) {
    return config.raw ? s : decodeURIComponent(s);
  }

  function stringifyCookieValue(value) {
    return encode(config.json ? JSON.stringify(value) : String(value));
  }

  function parseCookieValue(s) {
    if (s.indexOf('"') === 0) {
      // This is a quoted cookie as according to RFC2068, unescape...
      s = s.slice(1, -1).replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
    }

    try {
      // Replace server-side written pluses with spaces.
      // If we can't decode the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
      // If we can't parse the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
      s = decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
      return config.json ? JSON.parse(s) : s;
    } catch(e) {}
  }

  function read(s, converter) {
    var value = config.raw ? s : parseCookieValue(s);
    return $.isFunction(converter) ? converter(value) : value;
  }

  var config = $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

    // Write

    if (value !== undefined && !$.isFunction(value)) {
      options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, options);

      if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
        var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
        t.setTime(+t + days * 864e+5);
      }

      return (document.cookie = [
        encode(key), '=', stringifyCookieValue(value),
        options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
        options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
        options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
        options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
      ].join(''));
    }

    // Read

    var result = key ? undefined : {};

    // To prevent the for loop in the first place assign an empty array
    // in case there are no cookies at all. Also prevents odd result when
    // calling $.cookie().
    var cookies = document.cookie ? document.cookie.split('; ') : [];

    for (var i = 0, l = cookies.length; i < l; i++) {
      var parts = cookies[i].split('=');
      var name = decode(parts.shift());
      var cookie = parts.join('=');

      if (key && key === name) {
        // If second argument (value) is a function it's a converter...
        result = read(cookie, value);
        break;
      }

      // Prevent storing a cookie that we couldn't decode.
      if (!key && (cookie = read(cookie)) !== undefined) {
        result[name] = cookie;
      }
    }

    return result;
  };

  config.defaults = {};

  $.removeCookie = function (key, options) {
    if ($.cookie(key) === undefined) {
      return false;
    }

    // Must not alter options, thus extending a fresh object...
    $.cookie(key, '', $.extend({}, options, { expires: -1 }));
    return !$.cookie(key);
  };
```

Comment: do you need something other than jquery.min.js to run a cookie?

Comment: Yes. I have included that file. Its not because of the cookie code.

Comment: well its running fine without the cookie, so it has to be that, what file are you using?

Comment: I added the code for the cookie

Comment: OK i just copied the cookie code from Git hub, updating answer now

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a $ ( or jQuery as you are using ) in your if statement:

https://jsfiddle.net/mgd01a0x/1/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
         if($($.cookie('visits') > 1)){ // <------ here
           alert('top');
       }else{
       alert("bottom!");
       }
   }
});
```